# don't have jekyll-paginate or one of its dependencies installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-paginator

I have installed this [jekyll theme](https://github.com/steinvc/holo-alfa). But faced with one issue.

If I do:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

All work fine (`_site` folder contains necessary files and server is running), but if I use the following command:

```
jekyll build -d /var/www/budka/data/www/blog
```

I get the error:

> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate
>   or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as
>   currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error
>   message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If
>   you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at
>   http://jekyllrb.com/help/!
>
> jekyll 3.1.1 | Error:  jekyll-paginate

I tried to solve the issue, but unsuccessfully.
Now Gemfile file contains:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
gem 'html-proofer'
gem "jekyll"
gem 'jekyll-paginate'
gem "pygments.rb"
```

`jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)` gem is installed, because I see it in `gem list` commnad:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.5)
actionpack (4.2.5)
actionpack-action_caching (1.1.1)
actionpack-xml_parser (1.0.2)
actionview (4.2.5)
activejob (4.2.5)
activemodel (4.2.5)
activerecord (4.2.5)
activesupport (4.2.5.1, 4.2.5)
addressable (2.4.0, 2.3.8)
arel (6.0.3)
awesome_nested_set (3.0.3)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.11.2)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.8)
coderay (1.1.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
colorator (0.1)
colored (1.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.0)
css_parser (1.3.7)
erubis (2.7.0)
ethon (0.8.1)
execjs (2.6.0)
faraday (0.9.2)
ffi (1.9.10)
gemoji (2.1.0)
github-pages (48)
github-pages-health-check (0.6.1)
globalid (0.3.6)
html-pipeline (2.3.0)
html-proofer (2.6.4)
htmlentities (4.3.1)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
jekyll (3.1.1, 3.0.3)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1)
jekyll-feed (0.3.1)
jekyll-gist (1.4.0)
jekyll-mentions (1.0.0)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-redirect-from (0.9.1)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.4.0, 1.3.0)
jekyll-seo-tag (1.0.0)
jekyll-sitemap (0.10.0)
jekyll-textile-converter (0.1.0)
jekyll-watch (1.3.1)
jemoji (0.5.1)
jquery-rails (3.1.4)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
kaminari (0.16.3)
kramdown (1.9.0)
liquid (3.0.6)
listen (3.0.6)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.3)
mercenary (0.3.5)
mime-types (2.99)
mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
minitest (5.8.4, 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.11.2)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mysql2 (0.3.20)
net-dns (0.8.0)
net-ldap (0.12.1)
nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
octokit (4.2.0)
pandoc-ruby (1.0.0)
paperclip (4.2.4)
parallel (1.6.1)
passenger (5.0.23)
posix-spawn (0.3.11)
protected_attributes (1.1.3)
psych (2.0.5)
public_suffix (1.5.3)
pygments.rb (0.6.3)
rack (1.6.4, 1.5.2)
rack-openid (1.4.2)
rack-raw-upload (1.1.1)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.5)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (4.2.5)
rake (10.5.0, 10.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rbpdf (1.19.0)
rbpdf-font (1.19.0)
rdiscount (2.1.8)
rdoc (4.1.0)
redcarpet (3.3.4, 3.3.3)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
redmine_crm (0.0.22)
request_store (1.0.5)
rmagick (2.15.4)
roadie (3.1.1)
roadie-rails (1.1.0)
rouge (1.10.1)
ruby-ole (1.2.12)
ruby-openid (2.3.0)
rubyzip (1.1.7, 1.1.6)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
sass (3.4.21)
sass-rails (5.0.4)
sawyer (0.6.0)
spreadsheet (0.6.9)
sprockets (3.5.2)
sprockets-rails (3.0.0)
terminal-table (1.5.2)
test-unit (2.1.5.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.2)
typhoeus (0.8.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
vcard (0.2.12)
yajl-ruby (1.2.1)
yell (2.0.5)
```

Also, I added this row:

```
gems: [jekyll-paginate, jekyll-gist]
```

into `_config.yml` file, but `jekyll build -d /var/www/budka/data/www/blog` command does not still working.

Could you please advise how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A similar problem has happened to me! I found you have two versions of jekyll,jekyll (3.1.1, 3.0.3),which results in this phenomenon。
So uninstall one ：
First  run gem uninstall jekyll ,

```
 gem uninstall jekyll
   Select gem to uninstall:
     1. jekyll-3.0.3
     2. jekyll-3.1.2
     3. All versions
    > 2
    Successfully uninstalled jekyll-3.1.2
```

then run `Jekyll serve`.

Wish to help you!

Answer (score 17):

I have found the solution to the same error ***don't have jekyll-paginate or one of its dependencies*** following [this recomendation](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/jekyll-paginate-is-not-working-with-jekyll-3-0-1/1700):

Edit the **Gemfile** and add:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll"
gem "jekyll-paginate"
```

In my case, I have to add only to my **Gemfile** the

```
gem "jekyll"
```

And after I have edited the file, I ran in the terminal the commands:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
```

And this problem was solved...

Comment: I had the same problem but with almost zero-understand of ruby/gem/etc.  Gemfile is in your project folder, make sure the ```gem "jekyll-paginate"``` is in there, as well as your _config.yml file

Comment: yes +jj, I found the solution with the steps that I write in the answer

Comment: On Mac OSX 10.15 (Catalina), even with the Gem file installed you may need
`gem install jekyll-paginate --user-install`

That `--user-install` switch is needed to prevent the problem of “You don’t have write permissions for the /Library…” directory.

Answer (score 13):

Found a similar issue on [Jekyll repository](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4518), and [this comment](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4518#issuecomment-183823831) helped me solve it.

First run `gem uninstall --all`, then run `gem install github-pages`.

*P.S. You also don't need `jekyll-paginate` explicitly in your `Gemfile` as it's already included in `github-pages` gem.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I think that this approach is not suit me, because I have other gems which needed for working `redmine`, `apache` etc.

Comment: You can still reinstall those. The problem aren't any of the packages themselves, but rather that something got messed up when you were installing them the first time. I reinstalled all the gems I had before `uninstall --all`, and it now works properly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I am not a specialist in ruby and I just afraid that after removing and reinstalling all gems something will happen incorrectly with redmine, passenger etc. I have a lot of installed gems...

Comment: jekyll-sitemap are included at github-pages package, so try:
`gem install github-pages`

Answer (score 3):

just run `gem install jekyll-paginate`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. I get the error:

> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!

And I solved it by Edit the Gemfile! Add `gem "jekyll-paginate", "~> 1.1.0"` and it works!

Answer (score 1):

## What is the Problem

I had the same problem in jekyll 3.8.5 version and short error message is like below

`jekyll 3.8.5 | Error: jekyll-paginate`

## Investigate the Problem

Then I read my project Gemfile.

> If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
>   uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.

## Solution

So I did what it suggested, comment the `# gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.5"` and uncommented below line

`gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins`

then run `bundle update github-pages` and `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

Because github-pages have all necessary gem files, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem.

Here is a full list of steps for running Jekyll site (github pages) on MacOS

## Install bundler and jekyll

Copied from https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/

```
1. Install Xcode
2. Install Homebrew

Add RUBY to your PATH as 
   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

3. Install Jekyll

Add gems to your PATH as
   echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

## Running Jekyll site

**Restart** your terminal and go to your project's root directory.

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

If above command run into following error, then update the gemfile

```
 Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. If you've run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, ensure that you have included the jekyll-paginate gem in your Gemfile as well. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
```

## Fix

Gemfile is in your project's root directory. Add new gems to it as

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0"
gem "jekyll-paginate", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "jekyll-sitemap"
gem "jekyll-gist"
gem "jekyll-feed"
gem "jemoji"
```

Then

```
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Your site should be up at http://127.0.0.1:4000/