# jekyll serve shows a dependency erroe

Tags: web, jekyll, blogs, github-pages

While trying to run Jekyll serve on one of my website folders, I get the following error

```
 Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-sitemap 
or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as 
currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error 
message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-sitemap' If you 
run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at 
http://jekyllrb.com/help/!
```

How do I install jekyll-sitemap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the missing dependency:
Run `gem install jekyll-sitemap` and then try to run the Jekyll server again.

Another option If you have a file named  `Gemfile`, make sure it has a gem `jekyll-sitemap` at the base folder run `bundle install` and then bundle exec jekyll serve.

Also check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35401566/1165509).