# jekyll serve isn't working for dependency error

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

While trying to run the jekyll serve in GitBash(Win10),I got the following error:

```
$ jekyll server
Configuration file: D:/Blog/mysite/_config.yml
            Source: D:/Blog/mysite
       Destination: D:/Blog/mysite/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 3.25 seconds.
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-watch or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- ruby_dep/warning' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
jekyll 3.7.3 | Error:  jekyll-watch·
```

I was trying to solve the error via these ways:[jekyll serve shows a dependency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872341/jekyll-serve-shows-a-dependency-erroe),but it didn't work.

1. according to the prompt, I installed the jekyll-watch again, and then I ran `jekyll serve` again, the same error was coming up again. In other words, it didn't work for me.

   ```
   $ jekyll server
   Configuration file: D:/Blog/mysite/_config.yml
               Source: D:/Blog/mysite
          Destination: D:/Blog/mysite/_site
    Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
       Generating...
                     done in 3.25 seconds.
   Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-watch or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- ruby_dep/warning' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
   jekyll 3.7.3 | Error:  jekyll-watch
   ```
2. I tried to `bundle install`,and then ran `$ bundle exec jekyll serve`,the another error was coming...

   ```
   $ bundle exec jekyll serve
   D:/rubyInstall/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.3/lib/jekyll.rb:35:in 'require': cannot load such file -- i18n (LoadError)
           from D:/rubyInstall/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.3/lib/jekyll.rb:35:in '<top (required)>'
           from D:/rubyInstall/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.3/exe/jekyll:8:in 'require'
           from D:/rubyInstall/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.3/exe/jekyll:8:in '<top (required)>'
           from D:/rubyInstall/Ruby25-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in 'load'
           from D:/rubyInstall/Ruby25-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in '<main>'
   ```

Comment: Please post the output generated when you run `bundle show`

Comment: `Gems included by the bundle:
  * addressable (2.5.2)
  * bundler (1.16.1)  
  * colorator (1.1.0)
  * ffi (1.9.23)
  * forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
  * jekyll (3.7.3)
  * jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
  * jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
  * jekyll-sitemap (1.2.0)
  * jekyll-watch (2.0.0)
  * kramdown (1.16.2)
  * liquid (4.0.0)
  * listen (3.1.5)
  * mercenary (0.3.6)
  * pathutil (0.16.1)
  * public_suffix (3.0.2)
  * rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.10)
  * redcarpet (3.4.0)
  * rouge (3.1.1)
  * safe_yaml (1.0.4)
  * sass (3.5.6)
  * sass-listen (4.0.0)`

Comment: I'm very sorry about the format of the answer.I just got in touch with it,and I'm not familiar with this grammar.So...it's not yet inserted into the picture.please forgive me...

Comment: Never mind the format. From above I can see that `bundle install` did not complete successfully. Delete the **`Gemfile.lock`** and run `bundle install` once again..

Comment: Oh...the same error happened again! Could you tell me while gems  were missed ? Maybe I can install them directly.

Comment: What error did you encounter while running `bundle install`?

Comment: Accoring your way,the `Gemfile.lock` file had been found in path :`D:\rubyInstall\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\http_parser.rb-0.6.0`,and deleted it.Then I ran `bundle install`,the same gems were installed.While I was running  the `jekyll serve`,above error happend...

Comment: ![click the link](https://github.com/syt-honey/study_picture/blob/master/test.jpg)

Comment: sent a PR to one of your repo..

Comment: Wow!! It's working !!

Comment: ! [bundle exec picture link](https://github.com/syt-honey/study_picture/blob/master/bundleExec.png),.Hey~,thanks so much.It's finally settled!

Comment: You're welcome! :) Happy to know that you've finally resolved this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I asked you to post the output from `bundle show` is to assess if all the dependencies have been installed successfully.

If you go through the first error output, you'll see the following:

```
The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- ruby_dep/warning'
```

This means that the gem `ruby_dep` did not install properly. (`ruby_dep` is a second-order dependency of `jekyll-watch`)

So, the question here is,

*"Where you able to finish `bundle install` completely without any errors?"*

If no, you probably need to install the Ruby Devkit for your Ruby version by running the following:

```
$ ridk install
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I'm a beginner.    I remember that the ruby I installed was with Devkit,the link（the first in the directory） :https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/.

Comment: And the strangest thing is the `ruby_dep` was installed in my gems directory.

Comment: I have another problem ,how can I know how many dependencies the gem has ?(like you said ,`ruby_dep` is a second-order dependency of `jekyll-watch`),Where do I find it ?

Comment: The easiest way is to read through your `Gemfile.lock`. `jekyll-watch` depends on `listen` which in turn depends on `ruby_dep`

Comment: You say you have `ruby_dep` installed in your gems directory. If so, does it have a file at path `lib/ruby_dep/warning.rb`?

Comment: yup! There's this file.

Comment: okay please update your "question" with the output from running `bundle show`

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `Gemfile.lock` file and run `bundle install` once again.

This is what [@ashmaroli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704267/jekyll-serve-isnt-working-for-dependency-error/55201325#comment86430785_49704267) was suggesting in the comments and it worked.